# Implement weak-referenced Eventbus actors?

Tags: scala, akka

Is it correct to say that unreferenced actors remain subscribed to the event stream ? At least, that's what I get from experimenting with Akka...

I'm trying to implement weak-referencing for actors in an EventBus scenario. In those cases the event listeners/actors typically come and go. Unlike independent actors which are supposed to be present all of the time. Explicit unregistering of course does work. But I'm not always able to perceive the right moment to do this.

Does Akka provide in such a use case ?

```
val as = ActorSystem.create("weak")
var actor = as.actorOf(Props[ExceptionHandler])
as.eventStream.subscribe(actor,classOf[Exception])

// an event is published & received
as.eventStream.publish(new KnownProblem)

//session expires or whatever that makes the actor redundant
actor = null
(1 to 30).foreach(_ => System.gc)

// an event is published & STILL received
as.eventStream.publish(new KnownProblem)
```

Comment: `unsubscribe` actor from `EventStream` using `classOf[Exception]` classifier?

Comment: That will work. IF I could know the actor is not referenced in any way anymore. :-) I'm trying this scenario for an http session. When the apps server expires the session I have no occasion to run 'unsubscribe'. Usually that is done with weak references.

Comment: EventBus is attached to `ActorSystem` with `def eventStream`, also some events are published to `eventStream` during configuration.
I would suggest extend `EventBus` with subscription of `WeakReference[ActorRef]`-s, trait `LookupClassification` looks promising.

A quote from author: `Extend EventBus and implement.`
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/T3-FONxoX8E

Akka EventBus simple example
https://gist.github.com/3163791

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I could not actually implement it, but actor is stopping on GC. Using Scala 2.9.2 (REPL) + Akka 2.0.3.

The `EventBus` with `WeakReference[ActorRef]` did not help - because in Akka you also have a `dungeon` with `ChildrenContainer` (`self.children`), also there could be `Monitor` subscriptions to lifecycle events. The thing I did not try - creating actors with dispatcher that only knows about our new shiny `WeakEventBus` - so maybe I missed the point?

Here goes the code for REPL (start it with appropriate imports, and `:paste` it in 2 steps):

```
// Start REPL with something like:
// scala -Yrepl-sync -classpath "/opt/akka-2.0.3/lib/akka/akka-actor-2.0.3.jar:
// /opt/akka-2.0.3/lib/akka/akka-remote-2.0.3.jar:
// /opt/akka-2.0.3/lib/akka/config-0.3.1.jar:
// /opt/akka-2.0.3/lib/akka/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:
// /opt/akka-2.0.3/lib/akka/netty-3.5.3.Final.jar"

// :paste 1/2
import akka.actor._
import akka.pattern._
import akka.event._
import akka.util._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.dispatch.Await
import scala.ref.WeakReference
import java.util.Comparator
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._
import java.util.UUID

case class Message(val id:String,val timestamp: Long)
case class PostMessage(
  override val id:String=UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 
  override val timestamp: Long=new java.util.Date().getTime(), 
  text:String) extends Message(id, timestamp)  
case class MessageEvent(val channel:String, val message:Message)

case class StartServer(nodeName: String)
case class ServerStarted(nodeName: String, actor: ActorRef) 
case class IsAlive(nodeName: String)
case class IsAliveWeak(nodeName: String)
case class AmAlive(nodeName: String, actor: ActorRef)
case class GcCheck()
case class GcCheckScheduled(isScheduled: Boolean, 
  gcFlag: WeakReference[AnyRef])

trait WeakLookupClassification { this: WeakEventBus ⇒
protected final val subscribers = new Index[Classifier, 
  WeakReference[Subscriber]](mapSize(), 
    new Comparator[WeakReference[Subscriber]] {
          def compare(a: WeakReference[Subscriber], 
        b: WeakReference[Subscriber]): Int = { 
              if (a.get == None || b.get == None) -1
              else compareSubscribers(a.get.get, b.get.get)
        }
      })  
protected def mapSize(): Int
protected def compareSubscribers(a: Subscriber, b: Subscriber): Int
protected def classify(event: Event): Classifier
protected def publish(event: Event, subscriber: Subscriber): Unit
def subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber, to: Classifier): Boolean = 
  subscribers.put(to, new WeakReference(subscriber))
def unsubscribe(subscriber: Subscriber, from: Classifier): Boolean = 
  subscribers.remove(from, new WeakReference(subscriber))
def unsubscribe(subscriber: Subscriber): Unit = 
  subscribers.removeValue(new WeakReference(subscriber))
def publish(event: Event): Unit = {
      val i = subscribers.valueIterator(classify(event))
      while (i.hasNext) publish(event, i.next().get.get)
}
  }

class WeakEventBus extends EventBus with WeakLookupClassification {
  type Event = MessageEvent
  type Classifier=String   
  type Subscriber = ActorRef

  protected def compareSubscribers(a: ActorRef, b: ActorRef) = a compareTo b

  protected def mapSize(): Int = 10
  protected def classify(event: Event): Classifier = event.channel
  protected def publish(event: Event, subscriber: Subscriber): Unit =
      subscriber ! event
}

lazy val weakEventBus = new WeakEventBus

implicit val timeout = akka.util.Timeout(1000)
lazy val actorSystem = ActorSystem("serversys", ConfigFactory.parseString(""" 
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  actor {
        provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
        debug {
          receive = on 
          autoreceive = on        
          lifecycle = on
          event-stream = on
        }
  }
  remote {
        transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
        log-sent-messages = on 
        log-received-messages = on    
  }
}
serverconf {
  include "common"
  akka {
        actor {
          deployment {
        /root {
          remote = "akka://serversys@127.0.0.1:2552"
        }    
          }
        }
        remote {
          netty {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2552
          }
        }
  }
}
""").getConfig("serverconf"))

class Server extends Actor {
  private[this] val scheduled = new AtomicBoolean(false)
  private[this] val gcFlagRef = new AtomicReference[WeakReference[AnyRef]]()

  val gcCheckPeriod = Duration(5000, "millis")

  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) {
        self ! GcCheckScheduled(scheduled.get, gcFlagRef.get)
        super.preRestart(reason, message)
  }

  def schedule(period: Duration, who: ActorRef) = 
        actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period)(who ! GcCheck)  

  def receive = {    
        case StartServer(nodeName) => 
          sender ! ServerStarted(nodeName, self)
          if (scheduled.compareAndSet(false, true)) 
        schedule(gcCheckPeriod, self)
          val gcFlagObj = new AnyRef()              
          gcFlagRef.set(new WeakReference(gcFlagObj))
          weakEventBus.subscribe(self, nodeName)
          actorSystem.eventStream.unsubscribe(self)      
        case GcCheck =>
          val gcFlag = gcFlagRef.get
          if (gcFlag == null) {
        sys.error("gcFlag")
          }
         gcFlag.get match {
        case Some(gcFlagObj) =>
          scheduled.set(true)
          schedule(gcCheckPeriod, self)  
        case None =>
          println("Actor stopped because of GC: " + self)
          context.stop(self)        
        }
        case GcCheckScheduled(isScheduled, gcFlag) =>
          if (isScheduled && scheduled.compareAndSet(false, isScheduled)) {
        gcFlagRef.compareAndSet(null, gcFlag)
        schedule(gcCheckPeriod, self)            
          }
        case IsAlive(nodeName) =>
          println("Im alive (default EventBus): " + nodeName)
          sender ! AmAlive(nodeName, self)
        case e: MessageEvent => 
          println("Im alive (weak EventBus): " + e)       
    }   
} 

// :paste 2/2
class Root extends Actor { 
  def receive = {
      case start @ StartServer(nodeName) =>
        val server = context.actorOf(Props[Server], nodeName)
        context.watch(server)
        Await.result(server ? start, timeout.duration)
      .asInstanceOf[ServerStarted] match {
        case started @ ServerStarted(nodeName, _) => 
          sender ! started
        case _ => 
          throw new RuntimeException(
            "[S][FAIL] Could not start server: " + start)
        }
      case isAlive @ IsAlive(nodeName) =>
        Await.result(context.actorFor(nodeName) ? isAlive, 
      timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[AmAlive] match {
        case AmAlive(nodeName, _) => 
          println("[S][SUCC] Server is alive : " + nodeName)
        case _ => 
      throw new RuntimeException("[S][FAIL] Wrong answer: " + nodeName)    
          }
      case isAliveWeak @ IsAliveWeak(nodeName) =>                
        actorSystem.eventStream.publish(MessageEvent(nodeName, 
      PostMessage(text="isAlive-default")))  
        weakEventBus.publish(MessageEvent(nodeName, 
      PostMessage(text="isAlive-weak")))  
}
  }

lazy val rootActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Root], "root")

object Root {
  def start(nodeName: String) = {
        val msg = StartServer(nodeName)
        var startedActor: Option[ActorRef] = None
        Await.result(rootActor ? msg, timeout.duration)
      .asInstanceOf[ServerStarted] match {
            case succ @ ServerStarted(nodeName, actor) => 
          println("[S][SUCC] Server started: " + succ)
          startedActor = Some(actor)
            case _ => 
      throw new RuntimeException("[S][FAIL] Could not start server: " + msg)
          }
        startedActor  
  }
  def isAlive(nodeName: String) = rootActor ! IsAlive(nodeName)
  def isAliveWeak(nodeName: String) = rootActor ! IsAliveWeak(nodeName)
}

////////////////
// actual test 
Root.start("weak")
Thread.sleep(7000L)
System.gc()
Root.isAlive("weak")
```